# Can't access Kibana remotely - Can curl successfully on machine

Tags: linux, redhat, elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I've installed Kibana on rhel and am I'm trying to access remotely on http://server-url:5601.

I've installed elasticsearch and am able to access that remotely on http://server-url:9200

I've added

```
server.host 0.0.0.0
```

in the kibana.yml.

I've made sure the nsg is letting it through and have added to the firewall. I have also installed elasticsearch and that is working on port:9200 - What I did on the firewall and nsg for 9200 I did exactly the same for 5601 so I feel it's a config issue not a firewall issue.

Also I can successfully curl kibana from the machine locally

When running netstat -nlp | grep :5601 I get the below result:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5601          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      33072/node
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the exact error message you encounter?

Comment: So it's just the "This site can't be reached" error that you would normally get with a firewall issue. - ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is NOT a message you get with a firewall issue. It means that nothing is listening on that port. Check if kibana is bound to the correct interfaces and running (`netstat -nlp`).

Comment: I've ran the command and put the result in the main body of the question thanks for the info

Comment: Also if I curl localhost:5601 from the box I get the result so it's definitely listening on that port

Comment: As is suspected, it is only listening on the loopback device. Since you already changed the configuration, you either didn't restart the service properly after changing it, or you modified the wrong configuration file.

Comment: Ahhh ok so I was being an idiot. I initially started with service start kibana and then was trying to restart with systemctl. Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: If you commend on the main ticket I can happily mark answered if you'd like the points. Also do you mind telling me how you can tell it's only listeing on the loopback device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output of `netstat -nlp` is showing that Kibana is only listening on the loopback device `127.0.0.1`. Since you already changed the configuration, you either didn't restart the service properly after changing it, or you modified the wrong configuration file.

When the service is started using the edited configuration file it will be shown as `0.0.0.0:5601` instead.